Seamless alignment of background images?
I would like to highlight some cells in a table by underlying them with hatching patterns.
If two cells with the same pattern are next to each other, the pattern should cover both cells seamlessly.


table.demo {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

table.demo td {
  height: 100px;
}

table.demo td.stripes {
  /* Using  background-attachment: fixed;  is _not_ the desired solution, because the background no longer scrolls alogn with the table. */
  /* background-attachment: fixed; */

  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAYAAAAFCAYAAABmWJ3mAAAAIElEQVQImWNggIKOjo7/HR0d/xmQAbIAnI2hCocYYQAATEQPi+UvdB4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
}

table.demo td.B { background-color: #ffe; }
table.demo td.C { background-color: #efe; }
table.demo td.E { background-color: #eef; }
table.demo td.F { background-color: #fee; }
<table class="demo">
  <tr>
    <td class="stripes A">A</td>
    <td class="stripes B">B</td>
    <td class="stripes C">C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="stripes D">D</td>
    <td class="stripes E">E</td>
    <td class="stripes F">F</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="stripes G">G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td class="stripes I">I</td>
  </tr>
</table>



The details depend on the size of the preview area, so you may have to make the browser window larger or smaller to see the problem. Here is an enlarged screenshot of a place where four cells meet, demonstrating the problem:

The desired result and goal of this question is:

Already tried:

Using background-attachment: fixed; seems to solve the problem, but then the background image is fixed to the origin of the viewport, that is, it stops scrolling along with the table.

Applying the background image to the <table> element doesn't help, because it covers all cells, not only individually chosen ones.


Thus, the question is how the same seamless alignment can be achieved but keep the origin fixed to the <body>, the <table> element or anything else so that the hatches scroll along with the rest of the page contents.

you may set the repeating image inside table, then hide or mix it from each cells : https://jsfiddle.net/94ytch8p/  mix-blend-mode comes with many setting https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode#syntaxe choose the one that suits your need .. if any

@G-Cyrillus: This unfortunately only works if there is only pattern, as in the simplified table I used in the codepen above. My actual table is much larger and I would like to use several patterns with it, each indicating a different purpose, but two neighboring cells with the same pattern should still seamlessly meet.

You can simulate a fixed background attachment to only the table element by using pseudo-element that you position relatively to the whole table then using clip-path on the table cell to hide the overflowing part


table.demo {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative; /* relative here */
  z-index: 0;
}

table.demo td {
  height: 100px;
  clip-path: inset(0); /* this is important */
}

/* the background */
table.demo td.stripes:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset: 0; 
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAYAAAAFCAYAAABmWJ3mAAAAIElEQVQImWNggIKOjo7/HR0d/xmQAbIAnI2hCocYYQAATEQPi+UvdB4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
}
/**/

table.demo td.B { background-color: #ffe; }
table.demo td.C { background-color: #efe; }
table.demo td.E { background-color: #eef; }
table.demo td.F { background-color: #fee; }
<table class="demo">
  <tr>
    <td class="stripes A">A</td>
    <td class="stripes B">B</td>
    <td class="stripes C">C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="stripes D">D</td>
    <td class="stripes E">E</td>
    <td class="stripes F">F</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="stripes G">G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td class="stripes I">I</td>
  </tr>
</table>




Thank you, this works well and I've been able to generalize this to using multiple distinct patterns in the same table. (For example one common pattern for cells B, C, F and a different pattern for D, G, H.) However, it seems that the patterns are now in front of the text, that is, the letters A, B, C, … ?

@CarstenFuchs forgot the z-index declarations, added now

Wow, that's great! Thank you!  :-)

Here is a suitable solution.
Add background-position: center bottom;

Adding padding also to:table.demo td:height:100px; padding:10px;


table.demo {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

table.demo td {
  height: 100px;
  padding:10px;
}

table.demo td.stripes {
  /* Using  background-attachment: fixed;  is _not_ the desired solution, because the background no longer scrolls alogn with the table. */
  /* background-attachment: fixed; */

  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAYAAAAFCAYAAABmWJ3mAAAAIElEQVQImWNggIKOjo7/HR0d/xmQAbIAnI2hCocYYQAATEQPi+UvdB4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
  background-position: center bottom;
}

table.demo td.B { background-color: #ffe; }
table.demo td.C { background-color: #efe; }
table.demo td.E { background-color: #eef; }
table.demo td.F { background-color: #fee; }
<table class="demo">
      <tr>
        <td class="stripes A">A</td>
        <td class="stripes B">B</td>
        <td class="stripes C">C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stripes D">D</td>
        <td class="stripes E">E</td>
        <td class="stripes F">F</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stripes G">G</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td class="stripes I">I</td>
      </tr>
    </table>



Thank you.

This modifies the problem, but doesn't solve it: There is still misalignment both horizontally and vertically.

I added padding gap 10px to td element. That make it a little bit more better responsively. If that works for you. Thanks.
